# How To configure Hibernate as a JPA provider for Payara/Glassfish 4.1?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish, payara

Need a step by step guide for setting Payara/Glassfish 4.1 server to use Hibernate 5.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer in this article :
[Hibernate 5 in Payara](https://medium.com/@mertcal/using-hibernate-5-on-payara-cc242212a5d6#.aa3sbwlck)

Briefly, add Hibernate dependencies in your pom.xml, replace payara/glassfish jboss-logging.jar /lib with latest and then restart server.

Your project should have in the persistence.xml
its provider org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
and property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"